# I cant reach my new SQL instance

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows

I was using a older version of SQL on my server, and it worked fine when only typing the servername,, I could directly connect to the server,

I recently installed a new instance of SQL, and Iam trying to connect to the new instance but it dowsne't work.

SERVERNAME/New_instance

CAn someone help me out? How can I reach the new SQL server?

Comment: What is the error message that you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to allow both SQL Server & Windows Authentication

Do this by

1. In SQL Server Management Studio
2. Right click on Instance name
3. Select 'Security'
4. Select 'SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode'

Comment: Iasm trying to open with SQL managment studio but I can from my client,

Answer (score 1):

try servername\new_instance (notice the direction of the slash)

Answer (score 1):

are you trying to connect to the instance from your desktop, or from the local machine the instance is installed on?  if you're trying to connect from your desktop (aka remotely), you might not have remote connections enabled.  try turning this on.

Answer (score 0):

You might also need to turn on the SQL Browser Agent or whatever it's called.